# Not able to remove Connection header from Http request created by httpwerequest class

Tags: c#, file-upload, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I want to remove Connection header from my multipart upload request.But it is not getting removed even though I am setting HttpWebrequest.Connection property to null.I have also checked at runtime, the value is null.I tried changing the value at runtime to some other string, but it didn't even allow me that.I am getting a timeout issue while uploading large files through Httpwerequest, but I don't face such issue while using webclient class.After investigating through fiddler I found that the difference between requests generated by webclient and httpwebrequest is that webclient doesn't specify Connection header, but the httpwebrequest class does.And I want to use httpwebrequest as it is twice as fast as webclient class.So ,how do I get rid of connection header? Here is the code that I am using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = contentType;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.ContentLength = formData.Length;
if (headers != null)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
    {
        request.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value; 
    }
}
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Connection = null;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)